# How to use Pitivi to insert text in video?

Tags: pitivi

I have started using Pitivi in my Ubuntu 12.04.  Now I am able to make or edit videos using it. Can anyone tell me How I can insert text in videos using Pitivi? (Like the way Title Card comes in movies with different text transition effect)

Comment: You need to use Kdenlive to add text transitions. `sudo apt-get install kdenlive`

Answer (score 5):

You can use png images, I have used Gimp in the past to create text images.

The process is more less like this.

1. Start up Pitivi
2. Import the PNG-picture into the media-library
3. Drag the picture into the "track"-view
4. Import your video and drag it into the track-view too (below the picture).

You should see your text in front of the video.

Adjust the track-length of your PNG-resource to match the desired duration of your text.

**Resources:**

[Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1550963)

Comment: thanks @CoalaWeb for your reply. Yes it works. But actually I was looking for some short of transition of texts through the screen, like from down to up transition.

Comment: Ah I'm not sure about that but I'll do some research and see what I can come up with.